# Writing custom rules for CakePHP model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
use App\Model\Rule\CustomIsUnique;

$rules->add(new CustomIsUnique(['item_id', 'manufacture_unit_id']), [
    'errorField' => 'item_id',
    'message' => 'Item Unit must be unique.'
]);
```

On **CustomIsUnique** I've copy pasted codes of **IsUnique**

```
Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
```

But How to extend or add more operations inside the **__invoke** method ?

**Update** ::

```
   public function __invoke(EntityInterface $entity, array $options)
{
    $result = parent::__invoke($entity, $options);
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($options['type'] == 'item_units') {
            $data = TableRegistry::get('item_units')->find()
                ->where(['item_id' => $entity['item_id'],
                    'manufacture_unit_id' => $entity['manufacture_unit_id'],
                    'status !=' => 99])->hydrate(false)->first();
            if (empty($data)) {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif ($options['type'] == 'production_rules') {
            $data = TableRegistry::get('production_rules')->find()
                ->where(['input_item_id' => $entity['input_item_id'],
                    'output_item_id' => $entity['output_item_id'],
                    'status !=' => 99])->hydrate(false)->first();
            if (empty($data)) {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif ($options['type'] == 'prices') {
            $data = TableRegistry::get('prices')->find()
                ->where(['item_id' => $entity['item_id'],
                    'manufacture_unit_id' => $entity['manufacture_unit_id'],
                    'status !=' => 99])->hydrate(false)->first();
            if (empty($data)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is how I've  implemented for different model and passed extra parameter along with **options** array. I think this is not the good way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend a core application rule, you can do something like:

```
<?php
use App\Model\Rule;

class CustomIsUnique extends Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique
{
    public function __invoke(EntityInterface $entity, array $options)
    {
        $result = parent::__invoke($entity, $options);
        if ($result) {
            // the record is indeed unique
            return true;
        }
        // do any other checking here
        // for instance, checking if the existing record 
        // has a different deletion status than the one
        // you are inserting
    }
}
```

That will let you add any additional logic for your application.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for now.